# Proving that a number is a multiple of $6$ for every $n$

Tags: number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove that for every $n > 0$, the number $4^n + 3(7^{2n-1}) + 5$ is a multiple of $6$.

I tried to prove this by induction. If $n=1$, this is equal to $30$, which is equal to $6 \cdot 5$. I then suppose for the purpose of induction that $4^k + 3(7^{2n-1}) + 5$ is a multiple of $6$, so $4^k + 3(7^{2k-1}) + 5 = 6b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I need to show that $4^{k+1} + 3(7^{2k+1}) + 5$ is a multiple of $6$.

I have tried various ways of simplifying this using the induction hypothesis, including trying to solve for $3(7^{2k-1})$, but nothing has worked. I would like to take out a factor of $4$ in some way so that I can add substitute in the induction hypothesis. Most likely I would need to add and subtract some additional terms in the process. The middle term is causing a huge roadblock, because I don't think I can add and subtract a term dependent on $k$, since the only thing I know about $k$ is that it is at least $1$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to proceed? I will post an updated attempt as I work on this problem more.

Comment: Hint: try simplifications like $4^{k+1}-4^k = 4\cdot4^k-4^k = 3\cdot4^k$ to understand the difference between two consecutive terms in this sequence. (An alternative strategy is to prove separately that the quantity is both a multiple of $2$ and a multiple of $3$.)

Comment: Considering $7^{2n-1}\equiv 1\mod 6$ , it boils down to show $6\mid 4^n+8$. $4^n+8$ is clearly even and considering $4^n\equiv 1\mod 3$ gives $3\mid 4^n+8$ finishing the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier way without induction. For $n>0$, the number
$$4^n + 3(7^{2n-1}) + 5$$
is clearly even (even+odd+odd). So it remains to show that
$$4^n + 3(7^{2n-1}) + 5$$
is divisible by $3$. In fact
$$4^n + 3(7^{2n-1}) + 5\equiv 1^n+0+2=3\equiv 0\pmod{3}.$$